# Pagination: make current page bold

Tags: php

The following pagination works but does not make the current page, bold and unclickable (no href)

Whats wrong?

```
$totalcount = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as 'total' FROM $table");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($totalcount);

$pages = ceil($row['total'] / $perpage);

     for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {

        if ($i != $page)
            echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=$i\">$i</a> ";
        else
            echo "<b>" . $i . " </b>";

    }
```

Comment: where does the $page variable come from?

Comment: aha its the get var for page..it as called pagenum i see now...works now ty

Comment: @Bartek: We don't add *'[SOLVED]'* to the title here on Stack Overflow to mark it so.  (Not a messaging forum, etc.  See FAQ.) If you have answered your own question, please tell us in an answer and then mark it correct.

Answer (score 4):

where does `$page` come from?

and please sanitize your query!! … and your html

`SELECT * FROM $table` is as bad as satan himself